# Dll device connected for first time but it won't connect again

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, biometrics

DLL Method:

```
[DllImport("SBXPCDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern byte _ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, ref IntPtr lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord);
public static bool ConnectTcpip(Int32 dwMachineNumber, string lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord)
{
    if (lpszIPAddress == null)
        return false;
    IntPtr string_in = Marshal.StringToBSTR(lpszIPAddress);
    try
    {
        byte ret = _ConnectTcpip(dwMachineNumber, ref string_in, dwPortNumber, dwPassWord);
        return ret > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeBSTR(string_in);
    }
}
```

Button click event:

```
protected void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool status = sbxpc.SBXPCDLL.ConnectTcpip(1, ip, 5005, 0);
        if (status)
        {
            bool ss = sbxpc.SBXPCDLL.GetSerialNumber(1, out ip);
            Button1.Text = "connected";
            Response.Write("success" + ip);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        Response.Write(ee);
    }
}
```

I used SBXPCDLL.dll to connect biometric device. Code works for first time only, device connected but when run again it won't connect again. I don't know why? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you get for return value from `_ConnectTcpip`?

Comment: @Belurd just now i found out when i stop server and run again it will connect.Above code work fine for first time what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

You are connected to device after the first run, I suppose. To be able to connect again you have to Disconnect first (as I understood from "SBXPC Reference Manual" there is `Disconnect()` function).

Otherwise you can control your state in the application, i.e. if you are connected/disconected and run `GetSerialNumber()` depending on it.